# How to Selenium Locator Json File Load

Tags: python, selenium

There is a JSON file with locator information for the ID.

```
locatoro.json 
{
    "test":"By.XPATH, \"//*[@id='gb']/div/div[2]/a\""
}
```

Assume that you have loaded the Json file into Python
Then in Selenium

I want to implement click using code like below.

```
WebDriverWait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((Json['test'])).click()
```

But when I do Json['test'], it doesn't work. My expectation is

WebDriverWait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='id']")).click()

This is expected, but an error occurs.

I tried changing the text of the JSON file, but the result was the same

I'm not sure how to solve it. thank you

This is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait as WDW
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
import json

testFile = os.path.join('./locator.json')
testLoad = os.path.abspath(testFile)
with open(testLoad,'r',encoding='UTF8') as f:
    testData = json.load(f)

print(testData['test'])
"""
print result: By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gb']/div/div[2]/a"
"""
webDriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
wdw = WDW(webDriver, 10)

webDriver.get('https://www.google.com')
wdw.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((testData['test']))).click()
"""
the expected result
wdw.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gb']/div/div[2]/a"))).click()
"""
```

Comment: can u share the url of the page please

Comment: The URL is www.google.com thank you

Comment: which element is it on the google page?

Comment: This is Google sign in Button.

Comment: the locator you have posted, I don't see any element inside id='gb'

Comment: Would it be fine if I give you a code that clicks on sign in button?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the json file in the code above was finding the locator in Selenium and clicking didn't work properly.

I'm trying to manage the depth of a locator using a Python file dictionary.

If there is a better way, please suggest.

Here's the code:

locator.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

locatorData = {
    'google':{
        'signin':(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gb']/div/div[2]/a")
    }
}
```

signin.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait as WDW
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import locator

testData = locator.locatorData
webDriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
wdw = WDW(webDriver, 10)

webDriver.get('https://www.google.com')
wdw.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((testData['google']['signin']))).click()
```

Comment: When u r reading from the file, You are reading entire `'signin':(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gb']/div/div[2]/a")` right? so obviously that would be read as a string. `By.XPATH` should be mapped to a object `By.XPATH` in a dictionary and read the same